# How to open just one popup?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

I have this Javascript code :

```
function call() {
    popup = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');
    setTimeout(wait, 5000);
}

function caller() {
    setInterval(call, 1000);
}

function wait() {
    popup.close(call, 1000);
}
```

And I have this HTML code:

```
<body onload="caller();">`
```

And it opens an infinity of popups

I don't know how to open just one popup, not an infinity of files.

Comment: if you only want one popup, why use an interval to begin with? that's a REPEATED execution call. maybe you want setTimeout, which fires only once.

Comment: Do you want to open & close the window again and again ? If so you need to track the state of the popup (opened or closed) in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

When your `caller()` function runs, it calls the `call` function using `setInterval`, which will run on *ad infinitum*.

Instead, change this:

```
setInterval(call, 1000);
```

To this:

```
setTimeout(call, 1000);
```

This only calls it once, after 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

To open the popup once every time a user visits your page, you can use, i.e.:

```
<html>
 <head>
  your head
 </head>
  <body onload="popMe();">`
   your body
   <script>
   popMe(function(){ window.open('http://www.google.co.in'); }, 5000);
   </script>
  </body>
<html>
```